Failed to execute goal net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.1.0:codeserver
I am trying to create GWT project with Maven approach (manual archetypes). when i try to integrate Gxt with it and when i start the code server by run the below command:
mvn gwt:codeserver -pl *-client -am

I am getting this error:
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal [32mnet.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.1.0:codeserver[m [1m(default-cli)[m on project [36mmywebapp[m: [1;31mGWT exited with status 1[m -> [1m[Help 1][m
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal [32mnet.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.1.0:codeserver[m [1m(default-cli)[m on project [36mmywebapp[m: [1;31mGWT exited with status 1[m
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: GWT exited with status 1
    at net.ltgt.gwt.maven.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:73)
    at net.ltgt.gwt.maven.AbstractDevModeMojo.execute(AbstractDevModeMojo.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:328)
    ... 23 more


More logs are required, can you post the rest of the build?
